# Print alphabetical navigation list from an array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have an array of items and I am trying to generate an alphabetical navigation for them.

A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H etc...

- Apple
- Apricot
- Carrot
- Camel
- Dog

So I want to list every letter of the alphabet but only link the ones that have matching items in the array.

So far I have:

```
$productArr = array('Apple','Apricot','Carrot','Camel','Dog');

$previous = null;
foreach(range('A','Z') as $alpha) {
    $arrayCount = count($productArr);
    for ($i=0; $i < $arrayCount; $i++) {
        $firstLetter    = $productArr[$i];
        if ($firstLetter[0] == $alpha && $firstLetter[0] != $previous){
            echo '<li><a href="#'.$alpha.'">'.$alpha.'</a></li>';
            $previous = $alpha;
        }elseif ($firstLetter[0] != $alpha && $alpha != $previous){
            echo '<li>'.$alpha.'</li>';
            $previous = $alpha;
        }
    }       
}
```

It works fine up until the *elseif*, if you comment out the *elseif* it prints the list of links as expected. Just need to work out how to print the rest of the alphabet.

Any help as to where I'm going wrong would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: So I want to list every letter of the alphabet but only link the ones that have matching items in the array means you want to link only those alphabets which have array values starting with that alphabet.Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the secret is to move the elseif out of the inner loop.

```
<?php
$productArr = array('Apple','Apricot','Carrot','Camel','Dog', 'Rabbbit');

$previous = null;
foreach(range('A','Z') as $alpha) {
    $arrayCount = count($productArr);
    $printed = false;
    for ($i=0; $i < $arrayCount; $i++) {
        $firstLetter    = $productArr[$i];
        if ($firstLetter[0] == $alpha && $firstLetter[0] != $previous){
            echo '<li><a href="#'.$alpha.'">'.$alpha.'</a></li>';
            $previous = $alpha;
            $printed = true;
        } 
    }
    if($printed == false){
         echo '<li>'.$alpha.'</li>';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need one extra step to group the product first.

```
    $productArr = array('Apple','Apricot','Carrot','Camel','Dog');

    //This is the extra step
    $productArrGroup = array();
    foreach($productArr as $product){
        if(!isset($productArrGroup[$product[0]])){
            $productArrGroup[$product[0]] = array();
        }
        $productArrGroup[$product[0]][] = $product;
    }

    //You can even print the number of matching product for each $alpha like this !
    foreach(range('A','Z') as $alpha) {
        if(array_key_exists($alpha, $productArrGroup)){
            echo '<li><a href="#'.$alpha.'">'.$alpha.' ('.count($productArrGroup[$alpha]).')</a></li>'."\n";
        }else{
            echo '<li>'.$alpha.'</li>'."\n";
        }
    }
```

The result of the above code

```
<li><a href="#A">A(2)</a></li>
<li>B</li>
<li><a href="#C">C(2)</a></li>
<li><a href="#D">D(1)</a></li>
<li>E</li>
<li>F</li>
<li>G</li>
<li>H</li>
<li>I</li>
<li>J</li>
<li>K</li>
<li>L</li>
<li>M</li>
<li>N</li>
<li>O</li>
<li>P</li>
<li>Q</li>
<li>R</li>
<li>S</li>
<li>T</li>
<li>U</li>
<li>V</li>
<li>W</li>
<li>X</li>
<li>Y</li>
<li>Z</li>
```

Note: You might want to match letters case insensitively, in that case you can use `strtoupper` function to $product[0]

Answer (score 0):

Your `elseif` should be `||` not `&&`

```
elseif ($firstLetter[0] == $alpha && $alpha != $previous){
```

DEMO http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/i2q-97d

Comment: this prints each alphabet 5 times!

Comment: but we want to print all the alphabets....and link only those which are first chacaters in array....your answer prints only those present in array..Correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Please check this may be useful

```
<?php
// define indexed array
$animals = array("wolf", "lion", "tiger", "iguana", "bear","zebra", "leopard");
// sort alphabetically by value
// result: ("bear", "iguana", "leopard", "lion", "tiger", "wolf","zebra")
sort($animals);
print_r($animals);
?>
```

and this one :

```
$previous = null;
foreach($array as $value) {
    $firstLetter = substr($value, 0, 1);
    if($previous !== $firstLetter) echo "\n".$firstLetter."\n---\n\n";
    $previous = $firstLetter;

    echo $value."\n";
}
```